# ¿Se pueden usar comillas angulares en un texto manuscrito? ¿Qué comillas se usan en texto manuscrito para un tercer nivel de entrecomillado?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación, escritura-manuscrita

Dice el diccionario panhispánico de dudas:

> [**comillas**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=SSTAZ5sDyD6h59vijX). 1. Signo ortográfico doble del cual se usan diferentes tipos en español: las comillas angulares, también llamadas latinas o españolas (« »), las inglesas (“ ”) y las simples (‘ ’). Las comillas inglesas y las simples se escriben en la parte alta del renglón, mientras que las angulares se escriben centradas. En los textos impresos, se recomienda utilizar en primera instancia las comillas angulares, reservando los otros tipos para cuando deban entrecomillarse partes de un texto ya entrecomillado. En este caso, las comillas simples se emplearán en último lugar: *«Antonio me dijo: “Vaya ‘cacharro’ que se ha comprado Julián”»*. Las comillas se escriben pegadas a la primera y la última palabra del período que enmarcan, y separadas por un espacio de las palabras o signos que las preceden o las siguen; pero si lo que sigue a las comillas de cierre es un signo de puntuación, no se deja espacio entre ambos.

Como queda algo denso, recapitulo:

Tenemos tres tipos diferentes de comillas, cuyo uso prioritario es como sigue:

- comillas angulares, también llamadas latinas o españolas (« »)
- comillas inglesas (“ ”)
- comillas simples (‘ ’)

Por lo que un texto impreso se escribiría:

> «Antonio me dijo: “Vaya ‘cacharro’ que se ha comprado Julián”»

Vale.

Ahora mi duda es: si escribimos este texto a mano no tenemos manera de escribir las comillas angulares, latinas o españolas, ¿estoy en lo cierto? Suponiendo que no existe, seguramente escribiríamos:

> "Antonio me dijo: 'Vaya **‘cacharro’** que se ha comprado Julián'"

Pero `'cacharro'` estaría utilizando un tercer nivel de entrecomillado del que no disponemos. Por tanto, ¿cuál sería el criterio en este caso?

Comment: Yo nunca uso las comillas latinas pero si esa es la manera correcta, no veo porque no se pueda hacer a mano. ¿Acaso no es más flexible y adaptable un lápiz que un teclado? Tomaré nota de que esas comillas son las recomendadas en español y trataré de comenzarlas a usar.

Comment: @DGaleano a decir verdad, yo tampoco las uso nunca. Ha sido tras verlas muchas veces cuando he decidido consultar el DPD y me ha sorprendido que tengan la máxima prioridad.

Comment: También parece un poco raro que si las comillas angulares son prioritarias no se puedan escribir directamente desde un teclado en español, no están en ninguna tecla, habría que escribir su código o insertarlas desde un mapa de caracteres o algo así.

Comment: Yo las escribo a mano. No es difícil jaja. El teclado español no tiene “ o ” tampoco, solo " que es reemplazado automáticamente por las variantes en curva o ángulo. No sé con Windows, pero con el Mac es fácil. ( otras opciones incluyen usar el teclado portugués, que sí tiene dos teclados para « », o establecer sustituciones automáticos para transformar << a «. En Tex, `` se convierte interpreta como comilla de apertura, según idioma („ en alemán, « en castellano, portugués y francés, “ inglés estadounidense, ‘ inglés británico))

Comment: @guifa en linux también es fácil con una combinación de teclas pero no tienen una tecla fisíca en el teclado, o al menos compartida con otros símbolos, como las llaves, corchetes, etc. El texto del DPD dice que se "recomienda" pero aún así lo suyo es que estuvieran en los teclados en español

Comment: Es una cuestión interesante, se le podría consultar a la RAE si han hablado con los fabricantes de teclados para incluir las comillas angulares, o si estarían dispuestos a cambiar la norma dada la dificultad de escribirlas. En todo caso, no entiendo por qué dices que a mano no podemos escribir las comillas dobles, si con un boli puedes escribir cualquier cosa, como dice @DGaleano. ¿Igual no he entendido bien tu pregunta?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo bueno, técnicamente es posible, pero creo que en la vida he visto tal grafía en un texto escrito. Y por la forma en que el DPD lo menciona (_En los textos impresos..._), parece que no considere su uso para texto "a mano".

Comment: Entiendo. En todo caso, tampoco he visto en textos escritos a mano construcciones tan complejas... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que decís en los comentarios, sí es posible escribirlas a mano, por lo que no cuadra mi hipótesis de no utilizar las comillas angulares/españolas/latinas en texto manuscrito.

Por tanto, tanto en escrito a mano como en escrito impreso se utilizaría el mismo formato:

> «Antonio me dijo: “Vaya ‘cacharro’ que se ha comprado Julián”»

Comment: Acabo de encontrar en [fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/noticia/las-comillas-latinas-son-insolitas-en-textos-en-ingles/) una entrada que habla del tema de las comillas y dice: _«Sin embargo, el uso de las inglesas en textos en español no es incorrecto y de hecho estas se usan desde hace tiempo en libros y revistas, y son, además, las normales cuando se escribe a mano.»_ Así que lo nomal en textos manuscritos son las comillas inglesas (“ ”) aunque no queda claro como sería tu ejemplo con varios niveles de comillas.